# Function with pointer to a function and vector with default value as arguments results in compilation error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, function-pointers, initializer-list, default-arguments

Why following code does not compile on MSVC

```
#include <vector>

void func(double (* fptr)(double), const std::vector<double> & v = {})
{
}
```

I'm getting following errors.

> source_file.cpp(6): error C2065: 'fptr': undeclared identifier
>
> source_file.cpp(6): error C2062: type 'double' unexpected
>
> source_file.cpp(6): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
>
> source_file.cpp(6): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before ';'
>
> source_file.cpp(6): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
>
> source_file.cpp(6): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
>
> source_file.cpp(7): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
>
> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x64

When I remove either - vector default value:

```
void func(double (* fptr)(double), const std::vector<double> & v)
```

or the function pointer:

```
void func(const std::vector<double> & v = {})
```

errors disappear. Is it some MSVC bug or am I missing something?

Clang and G++ have no problems with the code.

You can check out the code with
https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual

Comment: What version of MSVC are you using?  This look like a bug to me.

Comment: @NathanOliver, on my own machine MSVC2015, rexester reports `Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506`.

Comment: OK.  I'm updating right now to the latest version of 2017 to test.  15.8.7 failed.

Comment: Alright, version 15.9.5 also fails with compiler 19.16.27026.1.  It looks like the issue has been reported to the developer community (can't figure out how to get a link) but it has no status or acknowledgement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it some MSVC bug or am I missing something?

You miss nothing. It's a MSVC bug. You can work around it by overloading:

```
void func(double (* fptr)(double), const std::vector<double> & v)
{
}

void func(double (* fptr)(double)) {
    std::vector<double> v;
    func(fptr, v); // or just func(fptr, {})
}
```

Though it's worth noting that taking the address of `func` is now ambiguous, unlike in your original, perfectly standard conforming code.

Comment: Use `func(fptr, {})` in the second function instead?

Comment: @NathanOliver - That too. I mean, I'd normally do it only when an optional non-const lvalue is needed, so it's a habit thing.